# How to use HTML tags for sending image NOT as an attachment in iOS 5

Tags: ios, email, ios5, ios4

I am trying to append image in HTML and send it through mail in iOS 5 based iPhone. I am using following code:

```
UIImage *emailImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(emailImage, 0.6);
NSString *imageStr = [imageData base64EncodingWithLineLength:[imageData length]];
NSString *htmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src='data:image/jpegbase64,%@'>",imageStr];
text=[text stringByAppendingString:htmlStr];
```

Its working perfect in iOS 4 but not in iOS 5. What is the reason behind and and how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you missing a semicolon? E.g.,

```
NSString *htmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,%@'>",imageStr];
```

When you say it works in iOS 4 but not iOS 5, what do you mean? That it shows up ok in iOS 4 Mail, but not iOS 5 mail? Or that the app, for some reason, that generates the mail, somehow fails in iOS5? Can you be more specific about the behavior difference between iOS 4 and 5?

Comment: I mean when I am sending mail from the device running iOS 4, then I can see the image when I receive the mail but when I sending the same mail from the device running iOS 5, image is missing and I only sees the "?" sign!

Comment: (1) did you add the missing semicolon?; (2) what mail program are you using to read the email send from iOS 4 and iOS 5? I assume you're not using the iPhone mail program, but rather your computer, e.g. Mac Mail or Microsoft Outlook; (3) have you examined the raw contents of the email (e.g., in Mac Mail, open the message, select "View" - "Message" - "Raw Source")? if so, how do the raw source of the emails generated by iOS 4 and iOS 5 differ?